# Is " Because I don't like him" incorrect?

Tags: syntax

> Because I don't like him.

Someone said it was a correct sentence. But I disagree. It is a dependent clause which can't stand alone.

> But she knows nothing about him.

Why is this sentence correct?

Comment: "Someone said..." Who is the "someone"?  Friend? Teacher? Book? Famous English writer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a fragment, but that's not necessarily a bad thing in conversational English. Fragments are common:

> What's that?
>
> A pencil.

The answer "A pencil" is clearly not a "sentence", but it is an acceptable response to the question.  Similarly

> Why didn't you talk to him?
>
> Because I don't like him.

That is an acceptable response. It is a correct fragment of a sentence, that works as part of a conversation. However, if you are writing an essay, you should avoid such fragments. These examples work because they are part of a dialogue. An essay is a monologue.

Comment: Sometimes brevity is employed as a form of emphasis, or of implying that an answer is obvious. Also, there is a modern fashion to follow  'Because...' with one word.  Why aren't you drinking vodka any more, Mother? Because Ukraine.

Comment: But there are so many great Ukrainian, Polish, Finnish, vodkas.....  Even Smirnoff (which is now technically British) - Which now begs the question... what will become of all the Russian Standard Vodka that has been taken off the shelves?

Comment: It could be used for disinfecting, like they do in Poland, and sometimes a large quantity can be re-distilled for use in industrial solvents.  I once knew a girl whose father, a Dubliner, (60 years ago) worked for HM Customs in the Port of London who used to bring decent seized Scotch or Irish home saying it was 'a shame to pour it away'. I daresay he wasn't alone.